# Adding SMINT v3.0 to Shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid, smint

Thank you in advance for the help.

Adding Smint v3.0 to Shopify:

- jquery.min.js and jquery.smint.js added to asset files
- added the following within the  tag of theme.liquid

  > {{ 'jquery.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}

> {{ 'jquery.smint.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}

- added Smint CSS mods into theme.scss.css.liquid

I'd like to know where I add:

> $(document).ready( function() {
>       $('.subMenu').smint({
>         'scrollSpeed' : 1000
>       }); });

and if I'm missing anything else to make Smint work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In `Assets` folder, you can paste

`$(document).ready( function() { $('.subMenu').smint({ 'scrollSpeed' : 1000 }); });`

at the end of either in **scripts.js.liquid** or **customscripts.js.liquid**

P.S. You can literally paste a `$(document).ready()` in any JS file that is called on a page.

*Addendum*

You can add the code in `<head>` section also.
Add this line right before `</head>`

```
<script>$(document).ready( function() { $('.subMenu').smint({ 'scrollSpeed' : 1000 }); });</script>
```

Another option. Add the above line right after `{{ 'jquery.smint.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response.  I'll need more clarification on this.

The Smint demo index.html file shows this to be contained with html script tags.

I'm unfamiliar on how to use Javascript and I'm unable to locate a scripts.js.liquid or customscripts.js.liquid file within my assets folder.  The other remain .js files appears to run a script with a beginning and end, and I'm concerned about "breaking" the script so to speak.